# php insert multiple dynamic input data into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this form data for images gallery and add dynamic input(add remove input field) using jquery for each new image:

```
<div class="row-1">
   <input type="hidden" name="list_item_image_large[]" value="">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control name="list_item_title[]" value="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control name="list_item_image_description[]" value="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control name="list_item_image_photographer[]" value="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control name="list_item_image_copyright[]" value="">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row-2">
   <input type="hidden" name="list_item_image_large[]" value="">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control name="list_item_title[]" value="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control name="list_item_image_description[]" value="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control name="list_item_image_photographer[]" value="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control name="list_item_image_copyright[]" value="">
   </div>
</div>
```

now after submit i have this data:

```
Array
(
    [list_item_image_large] => Array
        (
            [0] => uploads/images/posts/1586075502_3460aaee4378986bf677.jpg
            [1] => uploads/images/2020/04/1585774613_c2f7ed8d8b0458271371.png
        )

    [list_item_title] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [list_item_image_description] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [list_item_image_photographer] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

    [list_item_image_copyright] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )
)
```

now in action, i need to insert images data(title,description,photographer,copyright) for each image in mysql database. how do insert?!

Comment: one by one, just use regular loop and insert

Comment: @TraianGEICU:sure, can u add answer for more details, please.

Comment: other already give much details but maybe it's good also to check some tutorials for standard aspects

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to have a different structure.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [list_item_title] => value
            [list_item_image_description] => value
            [list_item_image_photographer] => value
            [list_item_image_copyright] => value
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [list_item_title] => value
            [list_item_image_description] => value
            [list_item_image_photographer] => value
            [list_item_image_copyright] => value
        )
)
```

With this structure you could just simply use a for(each) loop

```
for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
  // mysql_stuff, can access field values like this: $array[$i]['list_item_title']
}
```

But this would require a different naming on the html input fields.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control name="image[0][list_item_title]" value="">
...
<input type="text" class="form-control name="image[1][list_item_title]" value="">
...
```

Meaning the logic of duplicating the fields would be a little different, but handling the data after the submit will become much easier.

Comment: That would make life easier, assuming modifying the jQuery contraption is within the OP's abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate your data into individual items first. Something like this (fancier ways exist):

```
$items = [];

foreach($data['list_item_image_large'] as $num => $val) {
    $item[$num] = [
        'list_item_image_large' => $val,
        'list_item_title' => $data['list_item_title'][$num],
        'list_item_image_description' => $data['list_item_image_description'][$num],
        'list_item_image_photographer' => $data['list_item_image_photographer'][$num],
        'list_item_image_copyright' => $data['list_item_image_copyright'][$num]
    ];
}

var_dump($items); // See what you got there
```

You follow how the code above works, right? After that, it should be easy enough to insert the data into a database using your preferred method of interacting with MySQL. I assume you know how to insert data in general, and that you were simply struggling with the structure of your data.